# how to get textbox value inside a datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

if I have a datalist with textbox and a button inside and i want to access the value of the textbox and pass it to the listener of the button, anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Could you show the markup and some code? easier that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know how.

Let's say you have a `DataList` name myDataList, and a `TextBox` in it named by myTextBox.

```
foreach (DataListItem item in myDataList.Items)
{
    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("myTextBox");
    string text = myTextBox.text;
    // Do whatever you need with that string value here
}
```

This loops through all of the items in your `DataList` and places the value of your `TextBox` into a local string variable named "text".  From there, you can do whatever else needs to be done.

Comment: where should i write this code, and how to pass text as input in the listener of the button? thank :)

Comment: @MohamedAbdelHakim You could actually write this code in your button click event handler.